# How to trigger a keyframe animation multiple times (on every blur event)?

Tags: jquery, css-animations, keyframe

I have defined a simple animation like this:

```
@keyframes fullScale {
   0% {
      transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
      transform: scale(1);
   }
}
```

and attached it to a CSS class:

```
.updated-animation {
  animation: fullScale 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

then I tried to dynamically add/remove this class to elements that need to be animated whenever user's focus is lost. So, I used `onblur="update(this);"` on these HTML elements.The jquery code can be seen below:

```
function update(element) {
  $(element).removeClass('updated-animation');
  $(element).addClass('updated-animation');
}
```

**The animation works as expected only for the first blur event.**

However, subsequent events do not trigger the animation even though the event listener is invoked every time and I keep removing and re-adding the class. What is wrong with the code? **How is it possible to have the animation effect more than once on demand?**

Comment: You're removing the class then immediately adding it again, so I'm a little surprised it even works the first time at all. Could you please edit the question to include a full sample of the HTML and CSS

Comment: The first time it doesn't even have the updated-animation class. So it has no effect in removing it. Do you think I should add a timeout in between? When I try the same thing on the console it works as expected, which is really weird...

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. A timeout wouldn't seem to make any difference - the issue is that you're changing the state on blur, then immediately setting it back to the previous state again. Why would you do that? Surely you need to functions, one on blur to remove the class and anther on hover to add it

Comment: It doesn't have to do with hover. What I want is the element to animate only when focus is lost. But the animation should be replayed every time the same event occurs, that's why I'm trying to reset the CSS animation property by removing and adding the class back again.

Comment: It looks like timing was an issue after all. I tried adding a small delay before reapplying the class and now it works as expected.

setTimeout(() => { $(element).addClass('updated-animation'); }, 200);